Install .NET Framework 4.8.1 using Powershell script in Windows Server 2022 DC
I am trying to install .NET Framework 4.8.1 using Powershell script in Windows Server 2022 Datacenter. Can I install using Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1).
Please guide me with Powershell .ps1 script to install .NET Framework 4.8.1 in Windows Server 2022 Datacenter.
Please note manual download of the package/.exe is not allowed in our environment.

The dotnetfx package has 4.8.1 available, but it's currently marked as a prerelease (https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetfx/4.8.1.0-rtw). You can install it in a PowerShell script with choco install dotnetfx --pre. That said, this question isn't fantastic for this SO site.

winget install Microsoft.DotNet.Framework.DeveloperPack_4 --version 4.8.1, but note that this involves downloading an offline installer and executing it locally behind the scenes.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net481-offline-installer
you can download and install with paramerts:
NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe   /q /norestart 

The parameters can be found out
NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /?

powershell
start-Process -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -NoNewWindow -wait NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe

you can download and install the program from the SMB network directory, but you should remember that you may need to reboot

manual download of the package/.exe is not allowed in our environment.

@Izzy you can pre-download to the network installation directory and install from there.
